# How do I get data from json using a post request with python?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I go to this site https://www.marathonbet.ru/su/results.htm and I click on the September 11 button using Selenium, then I wanted to collect data from scrapy. But it didn't work. Data comes in json format from https://www.marathonbet.ru/su/react/results/list. scrappy returns empty space to me. How do I collect data? help please.

Comment: Can you not grab the results using selenium ? `driver.find_element_by_class_name("results")`

Comment: with selenium everything works out, I can't get json data

Comment: update the question with code you have tried, so someone can debug that.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html